# Solr indexing failed

Tags: solr, nutch

I did all like in [this tutorial](http://wiki.apache.org/nutch/NutchTutorial#A4._Setup_Solr_for_search), but there is some truble. When I try call `./nutch solrindex http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/ crawl/crawldb -linkdb crawl/linkdb crawl/segments/*` command after nutch crawling I get next exception

```
> WARNING: job_local_0001 org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Bad
> Request
> 
> Bad Request
> 
> request: http://127.0.0.1:8080/solr/update?wt=javabin&version=2
>         at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:430)
>         at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.CommonsHttpSolrServer.request(CommonsHttpSolrServer.java:244)
>         at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.request.AbstractUpdateRequest.process(AbstractUpdateRequest.java:105)
>         at org.apache.nutch.indexer.solr.SolrWriter.close(SolrWriter.java:142)
>         at org.apache.nutch.indexer.IndexerOutputFormat$1.close(IndexerOutputFormat.java:48)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask$OldTrackingRecordWriter.close(ReduceTask.java:466)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.runOldReducer(ReduceTask.java:530)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ReduceTask.run(ReduceTask.java:420)
>         at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:260)
```

What should I do to resolve this problem?

P.s. Solr is working. I used solr 4.1 and nutch 1.6.

Comment: whats the error in solr logs ???

Comment: I already resolved this problem. I change <field name="..." type="text" from some example in schema.xml to <field name="..." type="text_general" and all working fine. Can you give me your skype?

Comment: You can reach me on email on stack overflow

Comment: Thanks. But I don't know where I can find your e-mail. I didn't find it in your profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you got any exception, you should open logs and check that exceptions in log. In my case I modify `schema.xml` and insert some new fields with `type="text"`, but in my `schema.xml` was another type which called `text_general`, it was easy fix after logs reading.